# Strategy overview says "no data"

Tags: pine-script

I am having difficulty understanding why this strategy says "no data" on the overview window.  It shows me a positive net profit, ~150 total closed trades, and data in both the "performance summary" and "list of trades" windows.  Can someone help me understand why I'm not seeing anything in the strategy overview window where normally it compares vs hodl etc?

```
//@version=4
//@author=LasciviousMonk
strategy(title="TEMA/MAMA Cross", shorttitle="TEMA/MAMA Cross", overlay = true, 
  pyramiding = 0, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=50, initial_capital=1000, calc_on_every_tick=false,
  commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.1)

colorTransparent = color.new(color.black, 100)
colorMyGreen = color.new(#66bb6a, 0)
colorMyRed = color.new(#ef5350, 0)

sourceGlobal = input(title="Indicator Source", defval=close, type=input.source, group="Global Source")

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   TEMA Calculation with alerts (Based on TEMA With Alert by BerkSay)                         //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
showTEMA = input(defval=true, title="Show TEMA?", type=input.bool, group="TEMA")
lengthTEMAfast = input(title="TEMA Fast length", defval=13, minval=1, type=input.integer, group="TEMA")
lengthTEMAslow = input(title="TEMA Slow length", defval=34, minval=1, type=input.integer, group="TEMA")
sourceTEMA = sourceGlobal
showTEMAfill = input(title="Shade TEMA?", defval=false, type=input.bool, group="TEMA")

fTEMA(temaSource, temaLength) =>
    Tema1 = ema(temaSource, temaLength)
    Tema2 = ema(Tema1, temaLength)
    Tema3 = ema(Tema2, temaLength)
    3 * Tema1 - 3 * Tema2 + Tema3

slowTEMA = fTEMA(sourceTEMA, lengthTEMAslow)
fastTEMA = fTEMA(sourceTEMA, lengthTEMAfast)

longTEMA = fastTEMA > slowTEMA
shortTEMA = slowTEMA > fastTEMA

colorTEMAslow = color.new(#ff0000,20)
colorTEMAfast = color.new(#00ff00,20)
fillTEMA = slowTEMA>fastTEMA ? color.new(colorMyRed, 80) : color.new(colorMyGreen, 80)

plotTEMAslow = plot(showTEMA ? slowTEMA: na, color=colorTEMAslow, title="TEMA Slow plot", linewidth=2)
plotTEMAfast = plot(showTEMA ? fastTEMA: na, color=colorTEMAfast, title="TEMA Fast plot", linewidth=2)

plotshape(showTEMA and crossover(fastTEMA,slowTEMA) ? fastTEMA: na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, title="TEMA Cross Up", color=color.new(colorTEMAfast,10))
plotshape(showTEMA and crossunder(fastTEMA,slowTEMA) ? slowTEMA: na, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, title="TEMA Cross Down", color=color.new(colorTEMAslow,10))
fill(plotTEMAslow,plotTEMAfast, color=showTEMAfill ? fillTEMA : colorTransparent, title="TEMA fill")

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Ehlers MESA Adaptive Moving Average [LazyBear]                                               //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
showeMAMA = input(defval=true, title="Show Ehlers MESA Adaptive Moving Average", type=input.bool, group="Ehler's MESA Adaptive Moving Average")
sourceEMAMA = sourceGlobal
fastlimitEMAMA=input(.5, title="Fast Limit", group="Ehler's MESA Adaptive Moving Average")
slowlimitEMAMA=input(.05, title="Slow Limit", group="Ehler's MESA Adaptive Moving Average")
showEMAMAfill = input(title="Shade eMAMA?", defval=false, type=input.bool, group="Ehler's MESA Adaptive Moving Average")
var float p = na
var float i2 = na
var float q2 = na
var float re = na
var float im = na
var float spp = na
var float eMAMA = na
var float eFAMA = na
sp = (4*sourceEMAMA + 3*sourceEMAMA[1] + 2*sourceEMAMA[2] + sourceEMAMA[3]) / 10.0
dt = (.0962*sp + .5769*nz(sp[2]) - .5769*nz(sp[4])- .0962*nz(sp[6]))*(.075*nz(p[1]) + .54)
q1 = (.0962*dt + .5769*nz(dt[2]) - .5769*nz(dt[4])- .0962*nz(dt[6]))*(.075*nz(p[1]) + .54)
i1 = nz(dt[3])
jI = (.0962*i1 + .5769*nz(i1[2]) - .5769*nz(i1[4])- .0962*nz(i1[6]))*(.075*nz(p[1]) + .54)
jq = (.0962*q1 + .5769*nz(q1[2]) - .5769*nz(q1[4])- .0962*nz(q1[6]))*(.075*nz(p[1]) + .54)
i2_ = i1 - jq
q2_ = q1 + jI
i2 := .2*i2_ + .8*nz(i2[1])
q2 := .2*q2_ + .8*nz(q2[1])
re_ = i2*nz(i2[1]) + q2*nz(q2[1])
im_ = i2*nz(q2[1]) - q2*nz(i2[1])
re := .2*re_ + .8*nz(re[1])
im := .2*im_ + .8*nz(im[1])
p1 = iff(im!=0 and re!=0, 360/atan(im/re), nz(p[1]))
p2 = iff(p1 > 1.5*nz(p1[1]), 1.5*nz(p1[1]), iff(p1 < 0.67*nz(p1[1]), 0.67*nz(p1[1]), p1))
p3 = iff(p2<6, 6, iff (p2 > 50, 50, p2))
p := .2*p3 + .8*nz(p3[1])
spp := .33*p + .67*nz(spp[1])
phaseEMAMA = atan(q1 / i1)
dphase_ = nz(phaseEMAMA[1]) - phaseEMAMA
dphase = iff(dphase_< 1, 1, dphase_)
alpha_ = fastlimitEMAMA / dphase
alpha = iff(alpha_ < slowlimitEMAMA, slowlimitEMAMA, iff(alpha_ > fastlimitEMAMA, fastlimitEMAMA, alpha_))
eMAMA := alpha*sourceEMAMA + (1 - alpha)*nz(eMAMA[1])
eFAMA := .5*alpha*eMAMA + (1 - .5*alpha)*nz(eFAMA[1])

fillEMAMA = eMAMA>eFAMA ? color.new(#ffeb36, 80) : color.new(#f57c00, 80)

p_eMAMA = plot(showeMAMA ? eMAMA : na, title="Ehler's MAMA", linewidth = 2, style=plot.style_line, color=#ffeb36)
p_eFAMA = plot(showeMAMA ? eFAMA : na, title="Ehler's FAMA", linewidth = 2, style=plot.style_line, color=#f57c00)
plotshape(showeMAMA and crossover(eMAMA, eFAMA)? eFAMA: na, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, title="eMAMA Cross Up", color=color.new(#ffeb36,10))
plotshape(showeMAMA and crossunder(eMAMA, eFAMA)? eFAMA: na, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.absolute, size=size.tiny, title="eMAMA Cross Down", color=color.new(#f57c00,10))
fill(p_eMAMA, p_eFAMA, color=showEMAMAfill ? fillEMAMA : colorTransparent, title="eMAMA fill")

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Trade Options                                                                              //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
doTradesLong = input(title="Enable Long entries?", inline="direction", defval=true)
//doTradesShort = input(title="Enable Short entries", inline="direction", defval=false)

doTVtrades = input(title="Enable Tradingview trade entries?", defval=true)

// Limit backtesting dates
useDateRange = input(defval=true, title="Limit backtesting by date:", type=input.bool, group="Limit by date")

startDate = input(title="Start Date (DD/MM/YYYY)", type=input.time,
     defval=timestamp("1 Jan 2021 1:01 -0400"), group="Limit by date")
endDate =   input(title="End Date (DD/MM/YYYY)  ", type=input.time,
     defval=timestamp("31 Dec 2100 19:59 -0400"), group="Limit by date")

inDateRange = (time >= startDate) and (time < endDate)
inDateRange := useDateRange ? inDateRange : 1

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   Trade Actions                                                                              //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Alerts
longAlertCondition  = crossover(fastTEMA,eFAMA)  
longExAlertCondition = crossunder(fastTEMA,slowTEMA)

var inTrade    = false

longCondition  = barstate.isconfirmed and longAlertCondition and inDateRange
//shortCondition = barstate.isconfirmed and shortAlertCondition and inDateRange

// Long position entry
if longCondition and not inTrade
    inTrade      := true

    if doTVtrades
        strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)

    alert("Long entry", alert.freq_once_per_bar)

// Long position Exit
if longExAlertCondition and inTrade
    inTrade      := false
    
    if doTVtrades
        strategy.close("long", comment="exL")

    alert("Long Exit", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

Comment: The strategy works ok, even with default settings (NASDAQ:AAPL, 1D). Please provide symbol and resolution you using. Did you try to config `backtesting by date` setting in the strategy properties?

Comment: There must be something wrong in my browser or something.  All the built-ins have the same error, and (NASDAQ:AAPL, 1D) didn't work for me.

Comment: Try to delete browser cache

Answer (score 0):

I am embarrassed to admit that the graph wasn't showing up because I had that panel too small.  Once I made it large, the "no data" message disappeared and it was replaced by the graph I expected.